# Undefined is not a function, wysiwyg drupal7

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal-7, wysiwyg

I have the following code "js", and the browser puts this error "in line 8, "undefined is not a function". 
The line 8 is: $('.wysiwyg', context).once('wysiwyg', function () {

I have no idea about what happens!
Any suggestions? Thank you.

```
Drupal.behaviors.attachWysiwyg = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {
    // This breaks in Konqueror. Prevent it from running.
    if (/KDE/.test(navigator.vendor)) {
      return;
    }

    $('.wysiwyg', context).once('wysiwyg', function () {
      if (!this.id || typeof Drupal.settings.wysiwyg.triggers[this.id] === 'undefined') {
        return;
      }
      var $this = $(this);
      var params = Drupal.settings.wysiwyg.triggers[this.id];
      for (var format in params) {
        params[format].format = format;
        params[format].trigger = this.id;
        params[format].field = params.field;
      }
      var format = 'format' + this.value;
      // Directly attach this editor, if the input format is enabled or there is
      // only one input format at all.
      if ($this.is(':input')) {
        Drupal.wysiwygAttach(context, params[format]);
      }
      // Attach onChange handlers to input format selector elements.
      if ($this.is('select')) {
        $this.change(function() {
          // If not disabled, detach the current and attach a new editor.
          Drupal.wysiwygDetach(context, params[format]);
          format = 'format' + this.value;
          Drupal.wysiwygAttach(context, params[format]);
        });
      }
      // Detach any editor when the containing form is submitted.
      $('#' + params.field).parents('form').submit(function (event) {
        // Do not detach if the event was cancelled.
        if (event.isDefaultPrevented()) {
          return;
        }
        Drupal.wysiwygDetach(context, params[format], 'serialize');
      });
    });
  },

  detach: function (context, settings, trigger) {
    var wysiwygs;
    // The 'serialize' trigger indicates that we should simply update the
    // underlying element with the new text, without destroying the editor.
    if (trigger == 'serialize') {
      // Removing the wysiwyg-processed class guarantees that the editor will
      // be reattached. Only do this if we're planning to destroy the editor.
      wysiwygs = $('.wysiwyg-processed', context);
    }
    else {
      wysiwygs = $('.wysiwyg', context).removeOnce('wysiwyg');
    }
    wysiwygs.each(function () {
      var params = Drupal.settings.wysiwyg.triggers[this.id];
      Drupal.wysiwygDetach(context, params, trigger);
    });
  }
};

/**
 * Attach an editor to a target element.
 *
 * This tests whether the passed in editor implements the attach hook and
 * invokes it if available. Editor profile settings are cloned first, so they
 * cannot be overridden. After attaching the editor, the toggle link is shown
 * again, except in case we are attaching no editor.
 *
 * @param context
 *   A DOM element, supplied by Drupal.attachBehaviors().
 * @param params
 *   An object containing input format parameters.
 */
Drupal.wysiwygAttach = function(context, params) {
  if (typeof Drupal.wysiwyg.editor.attach[params.editor] == 'function') {
    // (Re-)initialize field instance.
    Drupal.wysiwyg.instances[params.field] = {};
    // Provide all input format parameters to editor instance.
    jQuery.extend(Drupal.wysiwyg.instances[params.field], params);
    // Provide editor callbacks for plugins, if available.
    if (typeof Drupal.wysiwyg.editor.instance[params.editor] == 'object') {
      jQuery.extend(Drupal.wysiwyg.instances[params.field], Drupal.wysiwyg.editor.instance[params.editor]);
    }
    // Store this field id, so (external) plugins can use it.
    // @todo Wrong point in time. Probably can only supported by editors which
    //   support an onFocus() or similar event.
    Drupal.wysiwyg.activeId = params.field;
    // Attach or update toggle link, if enabled.
    if (params.toggle) {
      Drupal.wysiwygAttachToggleLink(context, params);
    }
    // Otherwise, ensure that toggle link is hidden.
    else {
      $('#wysiwyg-toggle-' + params.field).hide();
    }
    // Attach editor, if enabled by default or last state was enabled.
    if (params.status) {
      Drupal.wysiwyg.editor.attach[params.editor](context, params, (Drupal.settings.wysiwyg.configs[params.editor] ? jQuery.extend(true, {}, Drupal.settings.wysiwyg.configs[params.editor][params.format]) : {}));
    }
    // Otherwise, attach default behaviors.
    else {
      Drupal.wysiwyg.editor.attach.none(context, params);
      Drupal.wysiwyg.instances[params.field].editor = 'none';
    }
  }
};

/**
 * Detach all editors from a target element.
 *
 * @param context
 *   A DOM element, supplied by Drupal.attachBehaviors().
 * @param params
 *   An object containing input format parameters.
 * @param trigger
 *   A string describing what is causing the editor to be detached.
 *
 * @see Drupal.detachBehaviors
 */
Drupal.wysiwygDetach = function (context, params, trigger) {
  // Do not attempt to detach an unknown editor instance (Ajax).
  if (typeof Drupal.wysiwyg.instances[params.field] == 'undefined') {
    return;
  }
  trigger = trigger || 'unload';
  var editor = Drupal.wysiwyg.instances[params.field].editor;
  if (jQuery.isFunction(Drupal.wysiwyg.editor.detach[editor])) {
    Drupal.wysiwyg.editor.detach[editor](context, params, trigger);
  }
};

/**
 * Append or update an editor toggle link to a target element.
 *
 * @param context
 *   A DOM element, supplied by Drupal.attachBehaviors().
 * @param params
 *   An object containing input format parameters.
 */
Drupal.wysiwygAttachToggleLink = function(context, params) {
  if (!$('#wysiwyg-toggle-' + params.field).length) {
    var text = document.createTextNode(params.status ? Drupal.settings.wysiwyg.disable : Drupal.settings.wysiwyg.enable);
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    $(a).attr({ id: 'wysiwyg-toggle-' + params.field, href: 'javascript:void(0);' }).append(text);
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    $(div).addClass('wysiwyg-toggle-wrapper').append(a);
    $('#' + params.field).after(div);
  }
  $('#wysiwyg-toggle-' + params.field)
    .html(params.status ? Drupal.settings.wysiwyg.disable : Drupal.settings.wysiwyg.enable).show()
    .unbind('click.wysiwyg', Drupal.wysiwyg.toggleWysiwyg)
    .bind('click.wysiwyg', { params: params, context: context }, Drupal.wysiwyg.toggleWysiwyg);

  // Hide toggle link in case no editor is attached.
  if (params.editor == 'none') {
    $('#wysiwyg-toggle-' + params.field).hide();
  }
};

/**
 * Callback for the Enable/Disable rich editor link.
 */
Drupal.wysiwyg.toggleWysiwyg = function (event) {
  var context = event.data.context;
  var params = event.data.params;
  if (params.status) {
    // Detach current editor.
    params.status = false;
    Drupal.wysiwygDetach(context, params);
    // After disabling the editor, re-attach default behaviors.
    // @todo We HAVE TO invoke Drupal.wysiwygAttach() here.
    Drupal.wysiwyg.editor.attach.none(context, params);
    Drupal.wysiwyg.instances[params.field] = Drupal.wysiwyg.editor.instance.none;
    Drupal.wysiwyg.instances[params.field].editor = 'none';
    Drupal.wysiwyg.instances[params.field].field = params.field;
    $(this).html(Drupal.settings.wysiwyg.enable).blur();
  }
  else {
    // Before enabling the editor, detach default behaviors.
    Drupal.wysiwyg.editor.detach.none(context, params);
    // Attach new editor using parameters of the currently selected input format.
    params = Drupal.settings.wysiwyg.triggers[params.trigger]['format' + $('#' + params.trigger).val()];
    params.status = true;
    Drupal.wysiwygAttach(context, params);
    $(this).html(Drupal.settings.wysiwyg.disable).blur();
  }
}

/**
 * Parse the CSS classes of an input format DOM element into parameters.
 *
 * Syntax for CSS classes is "wysiwyg-name-value".
 *
 * @param element
 *   An input format DOM element containing CSS classes to parse.
 * @param params
 *   (optional) An object containing input format parameters to update.
 */
Drupal.wysiwyg.getParams = function(element, params) {
  var classes = element.className.split(' ');
  var params = params || {};
  for (var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
    if (classes[i].substr(0, 8) == 'wysiwyg-') {
      var parts = classes[i].split('-');
      var value = parts.slice(2).join('-');
      params[parts[1]] = value;
    }
  }
  // Convert format id into string.
  params.format = 'format' + params.format;
  // Convert numeric values.
  params.status = parseInt(params.status, 10);
  params.toggle = parseInt(params.toggle, 10);
  params.resizable = parseInt(params.resizable, 10);
  return params;
};

/**
 * Allow certain editor libraries to initialize before the DOM is loaded.
 */
Drupal.wysiwygInit();

// Respond to CTools detach behaviors event.
$(document).bind('CToolsDetachBehaviors', function(event, context) {
  Drupal.behaviors.attachWysiwyg.detach(context, {}, 'unload');
});

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Based on past experience with Drupal, I'll guess that you have somehow loaded a second copy of jQuery onto the page. In this case, all the plugins get attached to the first jQuery, which then gets overwritten by the second one, and all plugin functions disappear.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you might be missing a jquery file defining the "once" function. Check with Firebug for Firefox (or a similiar development tool) where you can see the requested files for each page - clear the browser cache, then check Firebug's Net tab when reloading the page. If any files are not listed with a HTTP status code of "200 OK", you'll need to check that the files exist and have read permissions so the server can hand them out.

Anyway try to change line 8 as:

```
$('.wysiwyg:not(.processed)', context).addClass('processed').each(function() {
```

Comment: Oh! thank you very much! Now, I see toolbar wysiwyg!!! I only have another error "GET http://localhost:35729/livereload.js?snipver=1 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"
Do you know something about this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: It is a browser error, are you using Chrome?

If yes try these steps:
check the following settings to ensure that Javascript files were not being disabled:
 - Disabling all extensions
 - Settings -> Privacy -> Content Settings -> Javascript is enabled
 - Developer Tools -> Settings -> Disable Javascript is unticked

And...Try to paste the link on a different browser

Comment: @user3718166 Did you tried to open this page using a different browser?

Comment: @user3718166 Seems that the latest version of Chrome (33.0.1750.154) and Chromium  (34.0.1835.0) have a bug. In that case I suggest you to use a different browser.
Let me know.